# C allocation and memory overhead

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

Apologies if this is a stupid question, but it's been kinda bothering me for a long time.

*I'd like to know some details on how the memory manager knows what memory is in use.*

Imagine a one-chip microcomputer with 1024B of RAM - not much to spare.

Now you allocate **100 ints** - each int is **4 bytes**, each pointer **4 bytes** too (yea, 8bit one-chip will most likely have smaller pointers, but w/e).

So you've just used **800B** of ram for 100 ints? But it's worse - the allocation system must somehow take note on where the memory is malloc'd and where it's free - **200 extra bytes** or something? Or some bit marks?

---

- If this is true, why is C favoured over assembler so often?
- Is this really how it works? So super inefficient?
- (Or am I having a totally incorrect idea about it?)

Comment: just think about it, do you really need 100 distinct ints with pointers to each of them, or is an array of 100 ints, a pointer to the beginning and an int holding the size enough?

Comment: That's true, array would be good idea in this case - but still it must somehow know where it is?

Comment: Use an array of 100 `int`s, another `int` for the current size of buffer and another one to keep its capacity. Overall 408 bytes. "the allocation system must somehow take note on where the memory is malloc'd and where it's free", it sounds like Swiss cheese buffer to me, try to keep your buffer compact.

Comment: `So super inefficient` A program in C is ideally no more or less inefficient than it is designed to be. If you allocate 100 `int`s separately on the heap for no good reason, the problem isn't C, it's you.

Comment: All right, but I think we're getting side-tracked. My main concern was how the memory manager keeps track of what space is free for grabs and what's not.

Comment: That isn't C's concern, it's the OS's.

Comment: @user657267 There ain't no OS on an 8bit microchip, so?

Comment: Note that 1) the implementation of the C library is at liberty to use any kind of optimization as long as the general contract is held true. 2) The application is at liberty to allocate a big chunk of memory and implement its own optimized management of it. 3) You are at liberty of not going through `malloc()` *at all* but call OS functionality directly. -- All this adds power to C, and is in addition to Raphael's comment: You very seldom need 100 *seperate* `int` pointers, and if you do, you won't be any more efficient with Assembly anyway.)

Comment: That is the weirdest non-sequitur I've heard in a while...

Comment: That's funny.. why put on hold already answered question? Like if it had any effect..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It may surprise younger developers to learn that greying old ones like myself used to write in C on systems with 1 or 2k of RAM.

In systems this size, dynamic memory allocation would have been a luxury that we could not afford. It's not just the pointer overhead of managing the free store, but also the effects of free store fragmentation making memory allocation inefficient and very probably leading to a fatal out-of-memory condition (virtual memory was not an option).

So we used to use static memory allocation (i.e. global variables), kept a very tight control on the depth of function all nesting, and an even tighter control over nested interrupt handling.

When writing on these systems, I didn't even link the standard library. I wrote my own C startup routines and provided custom minimal I/O routines.

One program I wrote in a 2k ram system used the lower part of RAM as the data area and the upper part as the stack. In the final cut, I proved that the maximal use of stack reached so far down in memory that it was 1 byte away from the last variable in the data area.

Ah, the good old days...

EDIT:

To answer your question specifically, the original K&R free store manager used to add a header block to the beginning of each block of memory allocated via `malloc`.

The header block looked something like this:

```
union header {
    struct {
    union header   *ptr;
    unsigned        size;
    } s;
};
```

Where `ptr` is the address of the next header block and size is the size of the memory allocated (in blocks). The `malloc` function would actually return the address computed by `&header + sizeof(header)`. The free function would subtract the size of the header from the pointer you provided in order to re-link the block back into the free list.

Comment: You may be even more surprised to learn that these systems are still used even now.  If you work with embedded systems an 8bit processor with 1K of ram is all you may be given to work with.  The simple reason is cost vs. needs.

Answer (score 2):

There are several approaches how you can do that:

- <strike>as you write, `malloc()` one memory block for every `int` you have. Completely inefficient, thus I strike it out.</strike>
- `malloc()` an array of 100 `int`s. That needs in total `100*sizeof(int) + 1* sizeof(int*) +` whatever `malloc()` internally needs. Much better.
- statically allocate the array. Here you just need `100*sizeof(int)`.
- allocate the array on the stack. That needs the same, but only for the current function call.

Which of these you need depends on how long you need the memory and other criteria.

If you have that few RAM, it might even be questionable if it is useful to use `malloc()` at all. It can be an option if several code blocks need a lot of RAM, but not at the same time.

On how the memory addresses are tracked, that as well depends:

- for `malloc()`, you have to put the pointer in a place where you don't lose it.
- for an array on the stack, it is expressed relatively to the current frame pointer. The code sets up the frame and thus knows about the offset, so it is normally not needed to store it anywhere.
- for an array in the data segment, the compiler and linker know about the address and statically put the address where it is needed.

Answer (score 1):

> If this is true, why is C favoured over assembler so often?

You're simplifying the problem too much. C or assembler - doesn't matter, you still need to manage the memory chunks. The main issue is **fragmentation**, not the actual management overhead. In a system like the one you described, you would probably just allocate the memory and never ever release it, thus no need to check what's free - whatever is below the watermark is free, and that's it.

> Is this really how it works? So super inefficient?

There are many algorithms around this problem, but if you're simplifying - yes, it basically is. In reality its a much more complicated problem - and there are much more complicated systems revolving around servicing memory, dealing with fragmentation, garbage collection (on a OS level), etc etc.